# Displaying two columns page in a nested foreach using bootstrap cards

Tags: c#, bootstrap-5

I am using the code below to display cards with checkboxes.
I want to be able to display 2 columns of cards on my page and the checkboxes
section on the cards should have two columns as well.

At the moment I am just getting one column and the checkboxes are also displayed in one column as well.
How can I change this?

```
    @foreach (var header in NewProjectData.GroupBy(g => g.SectionHeaderName).ToList())
    {
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card d-flex align-items-center dynamic-card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">@header.Key</div>
                    @foreach (var item in header)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> @item.SectionChildText</label><br>
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@item.SectionChildText " id="flexCheckChecked">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample data of `NewProjectData.GroupBy(g => g.SectionHeaderName)` and sample of the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have atleast `div.row` wrapped over your first `foreach`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var header in NewProjectData.GroupBy(g => g.SectionHeaderName).ToList())
        {
           ...
           ...
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Second, by the nature of css, if there is only one `div.col` inside `div.row`, then obviously you will have only one column. So make sure you have 2 items in `NewProjectData.GroupBy(g => g.SectionHeaderName).ToList()`. Since you are looping over it, the number of items equals number of columns.

Comment: What do you mean by have 2 items in NewProjectData.GroupBy.... ? I don't quite get that

Comment: if you have only 2 item in `NewProjectData.GroupBy(g => g.SectionHeaderName)` then obviously there will only be 1 column

Comment: I have more than 2 items. I have 4. At the moment with the new row you ask me to introduce I am able to get two columns now but the content within the card is still one column. I want it to be two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating an entire row with a single column. Instead, repeat `col-6`, 2 columns every iteration...

```
           <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-title">@header.Key</div>
                  <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var item in header)
                    {
                        
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> @item.SectionChildText</label><br>
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@item.SectionChildText " id="flexCheckChecked">
                            </div>
                        
                    }
                  </div>
           </div>
```

[Demo (using React)](https://codeply.com/p/x9WuOByIEV#)